# Swift, Firebase - How Can I observe a node and send notification If app was closed

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, notifications, firebase-notifications

I have notification node like below, keep some actions to inform users each other. If app is working background I can send local notifications using `observeEventType(.ChildAdded ...` in tabBarVC Class. But If app closed It doesn't work.

I'm using Firebase, and connected Remote Notifications service with `pod 'Firebase/Messaging'` and so I can send only messaging. I want to filter like local notifications using `notification` parent node below.

**How could it be possible?**

```
notification
  notification_id0
    byUID:
    toUID:
    ownerID:
    type:
    content:
```

Also I have defined in **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** ..

```
let notificationTypes: UIUserNotificationType = [UIUserNotificationType.Alert, UIUserNotificationType.Sound, UIUserNotificationType.Badge]
let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: notificationTypes, categories: nil)
UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
application.registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
```

And this for remote Firebase notifications working well.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

   print("Meesage ID \(userInfo["gcm_message_id"]!)")
   print(userInfo)

}
```

Comment: So you want to send the notifications to the device and filter which ones result in displayed notifications on the device?

Comment: @ArthurThompson Yes I want like "@somone followed you" notification only its owner.

Comment: If your application is in the background then you will need to have a service that is watching the appropriate notes and use the FCM REST API to send a notification to the appropriate user.

Comment: @ArthurThompson Thanks but I don't know how can I do these. I have only swift knowledge, can you advice me somewhere or explain with samples much more?